# Star-Convex Set Centers Form Convex Set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I have the following proof that all centers of a star-convex set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $Z(U)$ form a convex set:

> Suppose $Z(U)$ is not convex, then there are elements $a,b\in Z(U)$ such that the connection $[a,b] \notin Z(U)$. However by definition, $a$ is a center of $Z(U)\subset U$, therefore the connection $[a,x]$ lies in $Z(U)$ $\forall x\in Z(U)$

Is this a sufficient proof and correct use of proof by contrapositive?

Comment: what is a "star domain"? what is a "center of a star domain"?

Comment: Sorry, but a simple google search will tell you what is a star domain..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However by definition, $a$ is a centre of $Z(U) \subset U$.

This isn't obvious: it's not going to be true for general subsets (For instance, an annulus is a subset of a disc, and while every point is a centre of a disc no points are centres of an annulus). In order to show that this is true for the specific subset $Z(U)$ it's not enough to have that the entire line $[a,b]$ lies in $U$ but also that every point on that line $[a,b]$ is also a centre.

Showing this is where the difficulty of this problem lies.

Hint: Try showing that any filled-in triangle, two of whose vertices are centres of $U$ and the third of which is any other point of $U$, lies in $U$.

Comment: I think your hint also needs the hypothesis that the third vertex is in $U$.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeling something was missing! The fact that all triangle edges are in U is clear from the definition of a center, but how do I get that the edge between the centers contains only centers? It's obvious visually, but that usually doesn't qualify as a proof. :)

Comment: @RubenKruepper I should have been clearer: I meant filled-in triangles, not just the edges. If I was doing it myself i'd just go straight to the arithmetic: have you seen that a triangle with vertices [a,b,c] can be parameterised $ta + sb + (1-t-s)c$ with $t \in [0,1]$ and $s \in [0,1-t]$?

Comment: No, I didn't know about the parameterization, thanks. Having shown this, I still fail to see how the fact that the triangle lies in U lets me deduce (formally) that all points on [a,b] are centers. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Every line from $c$ to a point on the line [a,b] lies in the triangle.